# Where to assign a variable inside a class component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a class component in react. I am trying to declare a variable that holds a number. Then use refrence that variable in an arrow function. The only problem is, **I get an error when I assign the variable in the class level scope.**

[image]

**I am brand new to react, and haven't done extensive JavaScript programming. How do I declare this variable so that it can be used in the arrow function.

**Full Code Below**:

```
class TabMenuButtons extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            rendersummaryAccordions: false,
            renderservicesAccordions: false,
            rendertravelAccordions: false, 
            renderratesAccordions: false, 
        };

    }


    let summaryCounter =  0;
   summaryAccordionsLogicGate = () => {

    this.setState({rendersummaryAccordions: true});
    console.log("summaryAccordionsLogicGate was called")
    summaryCounter = summaryCounter + 1;
  } 

  servicesAccordionsLogicGate = () => {
    this.setState({renderservicesAccordions: true});
    console.log("servicesAccordionsLogicGate was called")

  } 

  ratesAccordionsLogicGate = () => {
    this.setState({renderratesAccordions: true});
    console.log("ratesAccordionsLogicGate was called")

  } 

  travelAccordionsLogicGate = () => {
    this.setState({rendertravelAccordions: true});
    console.log("travelAccordionsLogicGate was called")

  } 



    render() {

        let summaryAccordionPlaceHolder = null
        let servicesAccordionPlaceHolder = null
        let ratesAccordionPlaceHolder = null
        let travelAccordionPlaceHolder = null

        this.state.rendersummaryAccordions && this.state.rendertravelAccordions === false   ? summaryAccordionPlaceHolder = <SummaryAccordions/> : summaryAccordionPlaceHolder = null;
        this.state.renderservicesAccordions ? servicesAccordionPlaceHolder = <ServicesAccordions/> : servicesAccordionPlaceHolder = null;
        this.state.renderratesAccordions  ? ratesAccordionPlaceHolder = <RatesAccordions/> : ratesAccordionPlaceHolder = null;
        this.state.rendertravelAccordions  ? travelAccordionPlaceHolder = <TravelAccordions/> : travelAccordionPlaceHolder = null;

        return (
            <div>
                <center>
                    <table cellspacing="30px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="ITEM" icon="pi pi-home"  className="TabMenuButtons" onClick={this.summaryAccordionsLogicGate}   style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%',  backgroundColor: "#1c479c" }}></Button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="ITEM" icon="pi pi-users"  className="TabMenuButtons" onClick={this.servicesAccordionsLogicGate}    style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%',  backgroundColor: "#1c479c"}}></Button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="ITEM" icon="pi pi-cloud"  className="TabMenuButtons" onClick={this.travelAccordionsLogicGate}  style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%',  backgroundColor: "#1c479c"}}></Button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <Button label="ITEM" icon="pi pi-money-bill" className="TabMenuButtons" onClick={this.ratesAccordionsLogicGate}   style={{marginRight:'.25em', borderRadius: '8%', backgroundColor: "#1c479c"}}></Button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </center>
                 <tr>

                    {/* EDIT THIS to become dynamic */}
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1>  ITEM: <em>$67,000.00 </em></h1> </td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> ITEM: <em>$5,000.00</em>  </h1></td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> ITEM: <em>$54,406.00</em> </h1></td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1>  ITEM: <em>1,000</em> </h1></td>
                    <td className="StaticTextBelowTabView"><h1> ITEM: <em>20.00%</em></h1></td>
                </tr>
                {ratesAccordionPlaceHolder}
                {servicesAccordionPlaceHolder}
                {travelAccordionPlaceHolder}
                {summaryAccordionPlaceHolder}
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: it's a class property, you don't need the `let` keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor you can do it like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      rendersummaryAccordions: false,
      renderservicesAccordions: false,
      rendertravelAccordions: false, 
      renderratesAccordions: false, 
  };
  this.summaryCounter = 0;
}
```

Make sure to also update how you reference it to include `this`:

```
summaryAccordionsLogicGate = () => {
  this.setState({rendersummaryAccordions: true});
  console.log("summaryAccordionsLogicGate was called")
  this.summaryCounter = summaryCounter + 1;
}
```

Since you evidently are using the babel plugin to do class properties, another option instead of explicitly putting it in the constructor is to do it as a class property:

```
summaryCounter = 0;
summaryAccordionsLogicGate = () => {
  this.setState({rendersummaryAccordions: true});
  console.log("summaryAccordionsLogicGate was called")
  this.summaryCounter = summaryCounter + 1;
}
```

Comment: OK this makes sense. I'm using this counter as a conditional to render another component. I was gonna make some logic to say if this number was even render (insert component here), do you think I should just make it a state boolean?

Comment: If you plan to use it to determine what to render, i definitely recommend you put it in state. And yes, a boolean makes sense if it just toggles back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you should put also `summaryCounter` in the state, but, if you really want to use some kind of "global variable" you can declare it in the constructor of your class in this way `this.variable = 0`

Comment: Thanks for the input I'm going to see if a state would work better for this case